# Java log waiting time for synchronized blocks

Tags: java, logging, concurrency, synchronization

I'm currently working on a big software project. At some point the software would stop executing the main thread for a few seconds and then continue. I'm unsure if this is caused by the GC or a concurrency problem. Increasing the memory did not lead to a less frequent stop in the thread.

So basically I'm searching for a way to log away the time a thread waited to obtain a lock on an object and where the waiting occured. Note that the time of these 'lags' is too slow to follow them in e.g. VisualVM in realtime, so I need some sort of logging.

Comment: can you take a thread dump when it happens?

Comment: It's unlikely that you'd have synchronized blocks that would last for seconds (unless you're working with bad programmers). Log the garbage collection and see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you enable GC logging and then see if the pauses correlate to the times when the GC is running.  That should tell you if this is a GC problem or a lock contention problem.  (The JVM option is `-Xloggc:filename` ... where `filename` is where you want the logging to go to.)

I don't think there is a way to "log" the time spent in waits on locks, but you might be able to do this with a specialized performance analysis tool.  (Try Googling for "java lock contention analyse".)

---

**UPDATE**

> I tried GC logging and it seems that actually the GC is blocking the main thread.

If you are using the default collector, a GC run "stops the world" while it does its stuff.  If you want to avoid this (or at least to *reduce* pause times), you will need to switch to a "low pause" collector such as the CMS collector or the G1 collector.  Refer to the Oracle GC Tuning pages for more information.

Comment: I tried GC logging and it seems that actually the GC is blocking the main thread. Thanks.